# Cannot stat file while copying script from deb package to /usr/local/bin in postinst

Tags: deb

I have a script (`nginx-sb-setup.sh`) inside of my deb package in `usr/local/bin` directory.

During postinst, I want to copy this `usr/local/bin/nginx-sb-setup.sh` which is inside of my deb package to `/usr/local/bin`.

I have learned that dpkg -i doesn't run in the same folder as the deb file. When I gave `pwd` in postinst, I have found that it runs in `/`.

And I unable to properly link the file in such way to successfully copy it to my target location.

During install, I get error saying,

> cp: cannot stat 'usr/local/bin/nginx-sb-setup.sh': No such file or directory

Please help.

Comment: _"dpkg -i doesn't run in the same folder as the deb file"_ - how so? If I download a `.deb` file, without exceptions I run `dpkg -i filename.deb` in the same folder the `.deb` file is in. I've not yet had to copy any files from inside the `.deb` package anywhere. Then again I never have `.deb` files in any `bin` directory either.

Comment: Where did you download the `.deb` package anyway and why? Ngnix.org has clear [installation instructions](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html) which don't involve downloading separate packages. Following them I just now installed it successfully on a Debian 11 system.

Comment: @StephenKitt, perhaps I should have posted file / folder structure of the package. Then you could have known that I have missed the `install` file. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My package was missing the `debian/install` file. Inside of the file, we need to write our local script and target location and it gets automatically copied.

The example `install` file looks like this,

```
usr/local/bin/nginx-sb-setup /usr/local/bin/
```

And the script gets automatically removed from `/usr/local/bin` during package removal; no need to remove it in `postrm`.